# Long Data Type Not Storing Long Value in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, long-integer, operator-precedence

When I execute the code below in excel VBA the first message box returns the long value correctly but when I store that value in a long data type and messagebox the long variable it returns 0 (?!).

```
Sub Test()

Dim lFileCount As Long
Dim lAdder As Long

lFileCount = 1

MsgBox 0.35! + (0.15! / lFileCount)

lAdder = 0.35! + (0.15! / lFileCount)
MsgBox lAdder
MsgBox Format(lAdder, "0.0")

End Sub
```

The reason for the exclamation points is due to the longs overflowing in the project I extrapolated the code from.  If I remove them it doesn't change the result.  I have no idea what could be causing this, my first thought is it has something to do with how the variable stores according to the order of operations, but I have no working solution.

I'm perplexed, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The exclamation points are making these literals *`Single` literals*. Without the exclamation point they would be *`Double` literals*, which is the default type for any floating-point literal in VBA. IOW you're *reducing* the precision with it - just drop 'em. Nobody uses type hints anymore anyway. Declare local `Const` with an explicit type instead of using magic/arbitrary numbers.

Comment: Thanks, Matt.  I was looking for double literals.  I DO need to get out of the habit of using magic numbers, this was a good reminder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long is a whole number.

I changed lAdder to Variant to collect a decimal value:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim lFileCount As Long
    Dim lAdder As Variant
    lFileCount = 1
    MsgBox 0.35 + (0.15 / lFileCount)
    lAdder = 0.35 + (0.15 / lFileCount)
    MsgBox lAdder
    MsgBox Format(lAdder, "0.0")
End Sub
```

---

Looks like my usage of As Variant was not appropriate, as shown in the comments to this answer.  As Double should be used for decimals:

```
 Sub Test()
    Dim lFileCount As Long
    Dim lAdder As Double
    lFileCount = 1
    MsgBox 0.35 + (0.15 / lFileCount)
    lAdder = 0.35 + (0.15 / lFileCount)
    MsgBox lAdder
    MsgBox Format(lAdder, "0.0")
End Sub
```

Comment: `Long` ***is*** an integer type. 32-bit, whereas `Integer` is 16-bit. "Acts like" doesn't sound right. And why on Earth would you use a `Variant` when you already know that the expression resolves to a `Double`?

Comment: @Mat'sMug I changed the statement about Long, which stores a whole number.  if you want to store a decimal, I am under the impression that you would use As Variant.

Comment: Decimals should be `Double` type variables.  `Dim lAdder As Double`

Comment: @tigeravatar Updated my post to reflect that.  My understanding was flawed, and though As Variant gave me the correct answer, didn't appear to be appropriate.  I thought Double was specific to an Array type, not that the data could be a decimal.

Comment: Accepted answer after the double.  Thank you!  My initial project did use doubles but I accidentally named the variable lAdder instead of dAdder, making me think it was a long.  Thank you, tigeravatar, for suggesting this and thank you, Cyril, for making the correction!

Comment: @user4333011 `lAdder` vs `dAdder` ... you need to read [this](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/), urgently. That's called *Systems Hungarian*, and it needs to be killed - with fire.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I will definitely read that.  I felt it was a bit of a strange practice when I started it, but it was definitely helpful in keeping track of types.  I'll read that article, though, and change my practice if it's mangaloid.

Comment: @Mat'sMug - So what would be a better way to name `Adder` variable to understand both it's purpose and type? Or, perhaps, I'll finally download RubberDuck and inspect my own code :)

Comment: @ScottHoltzman the type is irrelevant. Context is everything. If this were in a function named `CalculateCommissionRate` then `result` would be what I'd go with. Here... It's hard to tell what the intent is anyway ;-)

Comment: Thanks @Mat'sMug. So you are saying type is irrelevant because, for example, `result = 0.35 + 0.15` tells me automatically that it certainly isn't a string and most likely not a byte / int / long` and furthermore if `Dim result as  Double` is written right above or very close to it's my eyes can check type very easily anyway?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman exactly. Declaring variables as close as possible to their usage/assignment puts the context right where it needs to be :)

Answer (score 4):

> *The reason for the exclamation points is due to the longs overflowing in the project I extrapolated the code from. If I remove them it doesn't change the result.*

Read what you said. Twice. You don't need these *type hints*. Any floating-point literal in VBA is implicitly a `Double` - by type-hinting it with a `!`, you're making them `Single`, which reduces the size and precision of the type you would otherwise be using.

With a little bit of research on [**VBA data types**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/data-type-summary), you would have found that `Long` isn't able to hold floating-point values. A `Long` is a 32-bit integer, is all. So doing this:

```
Dim lAdder As Long
```

And then doing that:

```
MsgBox Format(lAdder, "0.0")
```

Makes no sense: the decimal portion of any integer value is always going to be 0.

And `0.35 + 0.15` is always going to be `0.5`, which converted to a `Long` is always going to be 0 as well:

```
Debug.Print CLng(0.5) 'prints 0
```

And this is what you're doing here, implicitly:

```
lAdder = 0.35! + (0.15! / lFileCount)
```

You're taking a `Double`, and assigning it to a `Long`. The result will be a `Long`.

Declare `lAdder As Double`, and problem solved.

That said, drop that `l` prefix. It's useless, confusing, and reeks of [**Systems Hungarian**](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/) notation, which serves absolutely no purpose but bloating up your code and making everything harder to read than it should be.

Comment: Excellent answer, also +1 for calling out the Systems Hungarian notation :D

Comment: Thanks Matt.  I was using doubles in my initial project and they were overflowing, I read the article [here](https://bytes.com/topic/visual-basic/answers/625485-overflow-long-variable-type) , implemented that solution, and I was no longer overflowing.

Comment: I still need to read the article on the Hungarian notation, but I DID find it useful to track datatypes.  And I had learned that long was an integer and forgot it when working on this :/

Comment: The Killer42 comment on that thread I linked to was the solution that prevented the overflow.

Comment: That's right, Mat's Mug!  We've met before here, and I remember Rubberduck.  I will re-check it out.  We only use the excel "IDE" here, is there a way to integrate Rubberduck into excel?  If I recall the IDE may have been the reason I didn't persue it further.

Comment: Oh Lordy, I am not a proper programmer, as I'm sure is apparent, and have rather become attached to Hungarian notation. Do I need to wean myself off it.

Comment: Okay, definitely worth re-checking out.  As you can tell I'm learning this as I go!  Thanks for all of your help and information, you know a lot about VB!